# Do you need commutative algebra for Milne's Algebraic Number Theory course?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I have completed Artin's Algebra. I was wondering if you need anything else or can I go ahead with Milne's course. I'm not providing a link since his lecture notes are very well known...

Comment: Google for "beware trivial inconveniences" for why providing a link is still considered good tone. Not providing a link because that essay is well-known :P

Comment: You should give up on the hope that you will form a complete and adequate background in subject X before beginning subject Y which depends on it. Start subject Y, and consult X as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the first few pages of [the course notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) to find out.

> **Prerequisites**
>
> The algebra usually covered in a first-year graduate course, for example, Galois theory, group
>   theory, and multilinear algebra. An undergraduate number theory course will also be helpful.

The name of the first chapter is

> 1. Preliminaries from Commutative Algebra

That should be enough to begin with. The first footnote to the first sentence in the first chapter says

> See also the notes *A Primer of Commutative Algebra* available on my website.

Those notes are found here: [A Primer of Commutative Algebra](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/ca.html).

Comment: I have sent Professor Milne an email. Hope he replies.